# Angular Style Dialog (Use @Import), changes main page

Tags: css, angular, styles

I want to import fontAwesome for my dialog-component-css, but the import affects also my main page.

The following import has been made in my dialog-component.css:

```
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);
```

Comment: could you share some more details?

Comment: If I open the Dialog in my Angular Application, some Icons are moving some pixels upwards in my navbar. These changes stays also if close the dialog.

Does the @import call have some sideeffects ?